# Python Pandas turn a dataframe into counts list or a vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have created the following pandas dataframe:

```
+------+-------+------------+
|userID|movieID|timesWatched|
+------+-------+------------+
|u1    |mv1    |5           |
|u1    |mv2    |2           |
|u2    |mv1    |1           |
|u3    |mv4    |30          |
+------+-------+------------+
```

I also have a list with 6 movies like this:

```
 movies =['mv0', 'mv1', 'mv2', 'mv3', 'mv4', 'mv5']
```

What I would like to do is to create for every user a list like this:

```
u1 : [0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0]
u2 : [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
u2 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0]
```

Is there a nice pythonic / pandas way of this, avoiding confusing for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and convert [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with the "list" format.

The `dropna=False` option of `pivot_table` combined with categorical data ensures to have all categories, even if all are NaNs.

```
movies =['mv0', 'mv1', 'mv2', 'mv3', 'mv4', 'mv5']

(df.assign(movieID=pd.Categorical(df['movieID'], categories=movies))
   .pivot_table(index='movieID',
                columns='userID',
                values='timesWatched',
                dropna=False, fill_value=0)
   .to_dict('list')
)
```